# How to set multiline string as value to json object

Tags: python

i want to add the multiline string posted below as a value to `json.loads(self.payload)`as follows

```
json.loads(self.payload)['evalscript']=self.evalScript
```

i tried after that to display the contents of the added value as follows:

```
        logger.debug("self.payload:",json.dumps(self.payload))
```

but the key and value i tried to add are not included in the object

how that can be achieved

**multiline string**

```
self.evalScript="""
        //VERSION=3
        function setup() {
        return {
            input: ["B02"],
            output: { id: 'default',
                    bands: 3 }
        };
        }

        function evaluatePixel(sample) {
        return [2.5 * sample.B04, 2.5 * sample.B03, 2.5 * sample.B02];
        }
    """
```

Comment: What's wrong with your first attempt? It looks ok in theory, just won't rewrite the json if that's what you're after.

Comment: @Peter ti uodated the question may it asnwers your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assign parsed JSON to any variable. [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) parses a JSON string and returns an `object`.

```py
d = json.loads(self.payload)       # assign object
d['evalscript'] = self.evalScript  # modify key
self.payload = json.dumps(d)       # to JSON string
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible to conver json.dumps(d) to object of type json please?how?

Comment: [json.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) returns a `str`. `loads` returns a `dict`like python object from a string. I'm not sure what you mean by object of type json.

Comment: If you mean content-type of an HTTP response, you should set return headers of your response for your specific framework: `Content-Type: application/json`. JSON payload will be a string.